# Downloading Blender 2.82

Tags: interface

I am trying to download Blender 2.82 but am getting and error. The source file can't be read according to Firefox. It takes forever to get the error message.

\AppData\Local\Temp\SgY4o2hI.msi.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.

Try again later, or contact the server administrator.

this is the error

Comment: Hello :). Works just fine on my end, have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Try using a different browser or a download manager.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work today after restarting my PC. I don't know why it was being an issue, probably something to do with my poor satellite connection.

Comment: I'm sure it has something to do with your connection. Can't believe that the *best browser in the world* isn't able to download something :)